# GKE pods to other VPC peered instance not reachable

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've created a VPC-native GKE private cluster. My Pod address range is 10.20.0.0/16 and my Service address range is 10.26.1.0/16.

GKE is setup on vpc-8 private subnet (100.17.8.0/24). I need to connect from pod to remote instances which are on another vpc, i.e vpc-2 (100.17.2.0/24 - this on different cloud) but getting below error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.private.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Tunnel established between vpc-2 and vpc-8. All my instances are in private subnets. vpc-8 instance able to telnet to vpc-2 private instance. But its failing from GKE ckuster pods as pods are using different CIDR 10.20.0.0/16 .

Please suggest any routing or connectivity changes needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue using ip masquerade daemonset created in GKE

REF: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/ip-masq-agent